# qmake generated makefile edits itself, breaking build

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, qmake

I've had this problem with qmake generated make files where when I run `qmake` it generates a makefile with the correct OBJECTS_DIR and DESTDIR variables set but when I run `make` on the generated makefile (`make -f Makefile.debug`) it somehow gets replaced with a Makefile which has them both set to incorrect values (ie - `./`).

It seems that it might do this when there's an error in the Makefile? If so why? Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I've tried changing how these variables are set in the qmake file, this has worked in the past but this time it did not.

Comment: Fixing the error (invalid `C_FLAGS` and `CXX_FLAGS`) seems to prevent this behavior, but I can't find that this is the problem because `make` created a new issue by changing those paths. I would still appreciate someone helping me figure this out

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 4.2.1